# Can the two titan powers inside Eren be separated and given to two different people?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So Eren

> Has the Attack titan and the Founding titan inside of him right?!

we can presume that if someone were to consume Eren

> they will gain the two titan powers together.

So can some one consume or gain just one of the titans? Like when the original titan(the original Ymir) divided her powers in to nine different powers and gave them to her descendants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a shifter dies not by getting eaten by a titan, their powers go to a random person. One can therefore presume that if Eren were to die, the two different titans would go to two different people.

Comment: do you have a source to confirm this, looks a lot like the devil fruit right now ;)

Comment: @Henjin From the wiki: http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_the_Titans "If an individual with the Nine Titans dies before their Titan can be inherited by being devoured, that Titan will be passed on to a random Eldian baby, regardless of distance or relation to the previous holder.[29]", it references chapter 88. I believe paged 23-24.

Comment: Somehow, I missed that information. Now that I think about it, a Titan Shifter can transfer his power just by commiting suicide. Interesting...